# How do you plot a pandas DataFrame using only the first element of a MultiIndex as the axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not totally convinced I've phrased the question correctly but here goes the explanation. Please do comment if I have mischaracterized the issue - I welcome the feedback.

After some manipulations I end up with a DataFrame that has an MultiIndex of tuples, each with a single element. I'm not quite sure why it's output as a MultiIndex even though there's only one element, and I'm not sure how to reference the element directly.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
np.random.seed(4)
df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':list('abbcdeefgh'),
    'b':list('gggghhhiii'),
    'c':np.random.randint(0,3,10)
})
g1 = df_test.groupby(['a','b']).sum() # sum over groups by a and b
g2 = g1.groupby(level=1).median() # median of sums of c in each group of b
g3 = g2.value_counts() # number of groups that have each median
g3
```

Result looks like a normal index

```
c
1    2
2    1
dtype: int64
```

i.e. there are 2 groups with median 1 and 1 group with median 2.

But:

```
g3.index
```

Gives:

```
MultiIndex([(1,),
            (2,)],
           names=['c'])
```

So when I plot that with `g3.plot(kind='bar')` the axis labels are "(1,)" and "(2,)" rather than the "1" and "2".

1. Why is value_counts() coming out with a MultiIndex and not with a straightforward single index?
2. What do I need to do to `g3` so that I can plot it with just the "1" and "2" appearing as axis labels rather than "(1,)" and "(2,)"?

Comment: `g2['c'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')` ?

Comment: @anky thanks I understand now! I was running `value_counts` on the whole DataFrame rather than on a series, hence it was returning a MultiIndex. Can you post this as an answer including the explanation and I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!